# Last record based on 2 column values

Tags: sql, oracle, max, multiple-conditions

```
pass_id retry_id
1       1
1       2
2       1
2       2
2       3
3       1
3       2
```

Need to pick up record with MAX(retry_id) within MAX(pass_id).

```
pass_id retry_id
3       2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is with `order by` and just choosing one row:

```
select t.pass_id, t.retry_id
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by pass_id desc, retry_id desc
     ) t
where rownum = 1
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/14155) is a SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE
   retry_id = (Select MAX(retry_id) FROM MyTable) AND 
   pass_id = (Select MAX(pass_id) FROM MyTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not positive on oracle syntax, but something like

```
SELECT MAX(retry_ID)
FROM Table
WHERE Pass_ID = (SELECT MAX(Pass_ID)
                 FROM Table)
```